# Spring MVC - Failed to read candidate component class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic-10.x

Iam getting following error when i try to deploy my ear in weblogic server 10g. Actually error doesn't show me the exact place where issue is generated.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/supplier_net/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_supplier-net_ear/9bdb97/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/com/fritolay/suppliernet/ecr/web/controller/TransportationController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:204)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1976)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1950)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1869)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3126)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Please help me to identify the issue.

Thanks
Prathap

Comment: So am stuck on the same problem do you got any right solutions for it. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

For anyone looking for the answer I got a similar error. I was using Java 8 lambda expressions and my Spring version was less than 4. It seems that there is no way that lambdas and old Springs can coexist, so the options are simple:

- Upgrade to Spring 4 or newer.
- Stop using Java 8 features such as lambda expressions.

Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same error using weblogic 12c (12.2.1.2.0). Updating to Spring 4 and adding

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

to my weblogic.xml resolved the issue.

Comment: Solved for me. My weblogic was using an old version of Spring classes embedded in a JAR located in the lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that the issue is with a spring-asm version conflict. Verify whether multiple version of spring-asm are being fetched.

Answer (score -2):

It certainly does tell you where the error is, and on the first line:

> /com/fritolay/suppliernet/ecr/web/controller/TransportationController.class];
>   nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51

Comment: That's the class name only , but i don't see the line number.Suppose if my class have n no of methods.Then how can i debug where the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred.

Comment: @Prathap - If you are using Eclipse, put break point on ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Pokuri: I am not using Eclipse to deploy i directly deploy to web-logic domain folder and start the web-logic server.Moreover i don't see this exception is coming from My code and its being thrown from Spring Classes.Still Don't know why?